# How is the key for the MAC shared in openid communication

Tags: python, security, openid

I was looking through the janrain python-openid, and I see the following params in the communication from the OP to the RP -

1) `openid.assoc_handle:{HMAC-SHA1}{50054f83}{NXBefg==}`

What are the two parameters after the algorithm name ? Is it the key ?

2)

```
openid.sig:eQwD7bcwAyfC9HrwQzEXFIGsKq8=
openid.signed:assoc_handle,claimed_id,identity,mode,ns,ns.sreg,op_endpoint,response_nonce,return_to,signed
```

The above two params are the signature returned by the OP, and the fields that were signed. How does the RP now decrypt the signature, I do not see a key being shared?

3) Alternatively, if the key is being shared during the request, then why can't an attacker get hold of it, and change the response ?

Thanks,
Murtaza